# How I can make specific group of users see export/import?

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

Is there a way to make a specific group of users see export/import

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. 
Hope you get your result from my answer.

```
<html>
<template id="export_hide_web" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
    <xpath expr="//link[@href='/web/static/src/css/data_export.css']" position="replace">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/web/static/src/css/data_export.css" groups="Your admin groupe" />
    </xpath>
    <xpath expr="//script[@src='/web/static/src/js/data_export.js']" position="replace">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/web/static/src/js/data_export.js" groups="Your admin group"></script>
    </xpath>
</template>
</html>
```

Comment: <template id="export_hide_web" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="//link[@href='/web/static/src/css/data_export.css']" position="replace">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/web/static/src/css/data_export.css" groups="Your admin groupe" />
        </xpath>
        <xpath expr="//script[@src='/web/static/src/js/data_export.js']" position="replace">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/web/static/src/js/data_export.js" groups="Your admin group"></script>
    </xpath>
</template>